# Rails: How do I login a Devise user in an integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, integration-testing

I am trying to test that a logged in user can access the admin page.

I have a user set up in the fixtures:

```
user_one:
  email: user_one@test.com
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password') %>
```

In the test, I log in and navigate to the admin page. But the test fails with a redirect.

```
class AdminTestLoggedIn < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "Log in" do
    post user_session_path, params: {user: {
      email:    users(:user_one).email,
      password: "password"
    }}

    get admin_path
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

I can see that the redirect points back to the login page:

```
  test "Log in" do
    ...

    assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path
  end
```

So, it looks like I haven't logged in. Where have I gone wrong? My guess is that I haven't handle the password encryption properly. If that's the case, how should it be done?

Comment: Thinking about this on the move: I think the problem is that the user is not confirmed.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993465/how-do-i-log-in-a-user-with-devise-for-rails-controller-integration-unit-tests?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I log in a user with Devise for Rails controller/integration unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993465/how-do-i-log-in-a-user-with-devise-for-rails-controller-integration-unit-tests)

Answer (score 8):

My initial test failed because I'd set users to `:confirmable` but user_one had no `:confirmed_at` date. Without confirmation, the user could not log in and therefore `admin_path` was redirecting.

The fix was to set `:confirmed_at` in `users.yml`:

```
user_one:
  email: user_one@test.com
  encrypted_password: <%= User.new.send(:password_digest, 'password') %>
  confirmed_at: <%= Time.now %>
```